# Run VMware inside nested VM hosted by Hyper-V

Tags: nested, vmware, virtualization, hyper-v

I work in an organization where we work on different projects, each of which has a developer image setup correctly with certificates, and many other things, which take more than a day to setup. We use Hyper-V for some images and VMware for others. As you know Hyper-V and VMware cannot run side-by-side.

As a developer I sometimes have to work on two different projects on the same day, solving bugs or whatever. 
(I only have one dev PC with Windows 10 host OS - company policy)
Ideally I would want to run everything inside [Qubes OS](https://www.qubes-os.org/intro/), but I am not allowed (yet...)

I would like to be able to run different VMs more or less at the same time. With different OS and other systems inside.

I found this article  (thanks to Dan Scott-Raynsford, and others)
[Run VMware nested inside Hyper-V](https://dscottraynsford.wordpress.com/2016/04/22/install-a-vmware-esxi-6-0-hypervisor-in-a-hyper-v-vm/)

I was able to run the script from the Win 10 host OS, but it did not work for me for the OS versions I have. I can run VMware Player 12 nested inside Hyper-V running Win Server 2012 R2 images. But when I try to start the virtual machine inside the VMware player I get this error:

[image]

I tried this command:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

But it did not solve the problem.

I was wondering if anyone made it work?
Or a better solution/suggestion for this problem?

Comment: did you make sure the hyper-v role is not activated on the windows server 2012 R2 image?

Comment: Yes. As far as I know I disabled it with "bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off"

Comment: maybe vmware checks if the feature is installed in your VM. so try to run `Remove-WindowsFeature -Name Hyper-V` in an elevated powershell on your Windows Server 2012 R2 VM.

Comment: Was the "Windows Hypervisor Platform" feature is unchecked too. I had to turn that off too for VMWare to start.